# flutter_beacon - Beacon Ranging / Monitoring process run in background

Tags: flutter, beacon, android-background, dart-isolates

I have used flutter_beacon Plugin to scan the BLE devices currently it is working fine.

I have already implemented the example of plugin's documentation
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon#-example-tab-

But when I navigate from homePage to anotherPage I want to run the scanning process in the background so I can access data in other pages also without re-in the plugins in other pages.

Is there any workaround here?